# How do I load strings as dtype('a3') from a TSV table?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Consider this sample TSV file:

```
$ cat table.txt
name
foo
bar
baz
```

I try to load it as `dtype('a3')` via:

```
df = pandas.io.parsers.read_table('table.txt', dtype='a3')
```

Unfortunately, the result of `print(df.name.dtype)` is `object`.

How do I load this data as `dtype('a3')`?

The motivation for this question is my wish to be as space and time efficient as possible. My assumption is that `dtype('a3')` is far more efficient than a generic, unoptimized `object`.

Comment: strings are represented as dtype object. memory use is very similar to the S/a types. pandas has a suite of string functions that are pretty efficient for strings in object dtype